# How to force seting incorrect or nonexistent foreign key index in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, indexing, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I have a simple table that contains 3 rows: a short text, its own ID and ID of another object.

I want to lose the association with that another object. I want to set its ID to 0 (such object does not exist). I can not use NULL because of other reasons.

Please help me to set table or row in MySQL Workbench to allow performing such operation.

Comment: Why can't you set it to `NULL`?

Comment: The point of using a NULL is for that very reason you posted the question for. If you can't use it, then what you imagined can't work and that's it.

Comment: Well the problem is that I'm using Erlang programming gen_server to query sql, and there is pretty hard to use null just like null. There is no such thing in Erlang. Every string or atom with word ("NULL") appears in query surrounded by quotes or double quotes... To really do the thing with null I have to write tons of code for every queries if I'd like to set NULL. So that is why I asked for some shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't "force" a value that violates a foreign key. That's the whole point of foreign keys.

You'll have to either

- Fix whatever doesn't like `NULL` values and set the value to `NULL` (that's what it's for, and this is the correct way),
- Create a dummy object with ID 0 so the reference works, or
- Remove the foreign key altogether.

Comment: Of your three answers first is the best, I know that, but I'm using Erlang gen server to query sql, and there is pretty hard to use null just like null. There is no such thing in Erlang. Every string or atom with word ("NULL") appears in query surrounded by quotes or double quotes...

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a dummy value such as zero to indicate a nonexistent value.  There are only two correct ways to deal with an optional association.  The first is to use nulls to indicate no association in a given instance.  The second is to rework your schema so as to conform to sixth normal form.

In sixth normal form, there will be an extra table that contains only your two ids.  In the case of no association, there will be no row. It's a simple as that.

Investigate Erlang more thoroughly.  Either Erlang is capable of dealing with NULLS or Erlang is incapable of dealing with SQL.  Like it or not,  NULLS are part of SQL.

Comment: Rework schema is impossible right now because of scale of this existing and working project.
I will try to deal with NULL in query again.

Comment: Keep in mind that the test for X=Y yields <unknown> if X is null, if Y is null, or even if they are both null.  Also, keep in mind that <unknown> is neither true nor false.  Thinking this way is not easy or intuitive.